# In Ruby, copying very large local variables to instance variables duplicates memory requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am passing some very large multi-dimensional hashes to a report view.  Because I am using Heroku, I am over running my memory allocation.  Since I have to duplicate these variables to pass them, I am doubling that requirement.  I am looking at using Redis to store and access the variables, but that is a significant effort.  Is there something that I am missing in passing these variables such that I do not duplicate them in the process?

The call from report.rb is:

```
message = KacMailer.daily_report(@associates, @managers, @assoc_wi_mgr, @assoc_sort, @issues, @items, @keys)
```

kac_mailer then duplicates the variables to pass them to the report view: (EDIT: added assignment of local variables to nil)

```
  def daily_report(associates, managers, assoc_wi_mgr, assoc_sorted, issues, items, keys)
    @associates   = associates
    associates    = nil
    @managers     = managers
    managers      = nil
    @assoc_wi_mgr = assoc_wi_mgr
    assoc_wi_mgr  = nil
    @assoc_sorted = assoc_sorted
    assoc_sorted  = nil
    @issues       = issues
    issues        = nil
    @items        = items
    items         = nil
    @keys         = keys
    keys          = nil

    support_mail = mail(to: $kac.support, subject: 'Daily Report', from: $kac.support) do |format|
      format.html { render 'kac_mailer/daily_report' }

    end
  end
```

Comment: There's no duplication here, just references- that doesn't duplicate the data.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd like to agree but, if I did, setting the local variables to nil would also set the instance variables.  That does not happen.

Comment: @DaveNewton No, okay, I think I see it.  Setting those local variables to nil changed their pointers, but the same memory is held by the instance variables.  What this means is that I do need to switch to Redis, I guess, as there is no real way to decrease that allocation.

Comment: Have you considered passing around an array of the object ids instead of the full objects?

Comment: @TarynEast  I like the idea, but they are not model objects.  The report model reviews all of the tables, running analytics and comparisons, to produce the resultant hashes in a form ready for the report view.  For most, but not all of them, they have no direct object.  For those that do, I've pulled the variables I need.  Thanks.

Comment: hmm... I'm not yet sure why you need to duplicate them at all - can you show us a bit more of your code?

Comment: @DaveNewton  Please post your response as the definitive answer to the specific question and I will accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no duplication here, just references–that doesn't duplicate the data.

Duplication implies creating clone/copy of the large structures. Referencing the data again adds only that new reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the variables were not duplicated but only gained a new pointer.  This meant the memory requirement was very difficult to resolve.  The hashes are very complex and they are created and used so dynamically that even Redis is a difficult solution.  In terms of price/performance, my best option was simply to increase the memory available by increasing the size of the dynamic worker dyno in Heroku Scheduler.  This was easy and worked great.